# Unable to compile arduino code in platfromio

Tags: arduino, attiny, platformio

I am unable to compile bellow code in platfromIO. 
But which is successfully compiled in arduino 1.5 IDE

```
#define PRESSED LOW
#define NOT_PRESSED HIGH

const byte led = 13;
#define shortPress  100
#define longPress  500

long blinkInterval = 500;
unsigned long previousBlink=0;
bool ledState = true;
bool blinkState = true;

typedef struct Buttons {
    const byte pin = 2;
    const int debounce = 10;

    unsigned long counter=0;
    bool prevState = NOT_PRESSED;
    bool currentState;
} Button;

// create a Button variable type
Button button;

void setup() {
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(button.pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
    // check the button
    button.currentState = digitalRead(button.pin);

    // has it changed?
    if (button.currentState != button.prevState) {
        delay(button.debounce);
        // update status in case of bounce
        button.currentState = digitalRead(button.pin);
        if (button.currentState == PRESSED) {
            // a new press event occured
            // record when button went down
            button.counter = millis();
        }

        if (button.currentState == NOT_PRESSED) {
            // but no longer pressed, how long was it down?
            unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
            //if ((currentMillis - button.counter >= shortPress) && !(currentMillis - button.counter >= longPress)) {
            if ((currentMillis - button.counter >= shortPress) && !(currentMillis - button.counter >= longPress)) {
                // short press detected. 
                handleShortPress();
            }
            if ((currentMillis - button.counter >= longPress)) {
                // the long press was detected
                handleLongPress();
            }
        }
        // used to detect when state changes
        button.prevState = button.currentState;
    } 

    blinkLED();
}

void handleShortPress() {
    blinkState = true;
    ledState = true;
    blinkInterval = blinkInterval / 2;
    if (blinkInterval <= 50)
        blinkInterval = 500;
}

void handleLongPress() {
    blinkState = false;
    ledState = false;
}

void blinkLED() {
    // blink the LED (or don't!)
    if (blinkState) {
        if (millis() - previousBlink >= blinkInterval) {
            // blink the LED
            ledState = !ledState;
            previousBlink = millis();
        }
    } else {
        ledState = false;
    }
    digitalWrite(led, ledState);
}
```

Here is the platformio.ini

```
[env:attiny13]
platform = atmelavr
board = attiny13
framework = arduino
```

Compile output of PIO

> ```
> Processing attiny13 (platform: atmelavr; board: attiny13; framework: arduino)
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
> CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/atmelavr/attiny13.html
> PLATFORM: Atmel AVR 1.15.0 > Generic ATtiny13
> HARDWARE: ATTINY13 1MHz, 64B RAM, 1KB Flash
> PACKAGES: toolchain-atmelavr 1.50400.190710 (5.4.0), framework-arduinoavr 4.1.2
> LDF: Library Dependency Finder -> xxxxxx
> LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
> Found 0 compatible libraries
> Scanning dependencies...
> No dependencies
> Compiling .pio/build/attiny13/src/Blink.cpp.o
> src/Blink.cpp: In function 'void setup()':
> src/Blink.cpp:33:23: error: 'INPUT_PULLUP' was not declared in this scope
>    pinMode(button.pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
>                        ^
> *** [.pio/build/attiny13/src/Blink.cpp.o] Error 1
> ```
>
> ## ============================================================================ [FAILED] Took 1.31 seconds
>
> ```
> The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
>
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
> ```

Do I need to amend the code for PlatromIO ?

However when I comment on the INPUT_PULLUP line. I am able to compile in PIO but output binary size is higher with compared to Arduino IDE ?

Can you suggest any flags or configurations to optimize the binary size ?

Comment: "I am unable to compile bellow code in platfromIO" - is there any error message?

Comment: Yes, I added to the description

Comment: Have you included the Arduino library on top of your code? If not, try adding `#include <Arduino.h>` at the very top of your file and recompile.

Comment: Yes, I did. But that doesn't work

Comment: Hi, Janaka, are you able to define your button.pin property as INPUT, instead of INPUT_PULLUP?

Comment: Then what about the binary size different in both IDEs ?